# String reverse in another way

Tags: php, string

I'm searching for a function which can reverse a string in another way.
it should always takes the last and the first char of the string.
In example the string

```
123456
```

should become

```
615243
```

Is there any php function?

EDIT

This is my code so far

```
$mystring = "1234";

$start = 0;
$end = strlen($mystring);
$direction = 1;

$new_str = '';

while ($start === $end) {
    if ($direction == 0) {
        $new_str .= substr($mystring, $start, 1);
        $start++;
        $direction = 1;
    } else {
        $new_str .= substr($mystring, $end, -1);
        $end--;
        $direction = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or should we just write your code?!

Comment: I think 615243 should be 654321? Please be more clear.

Comment: How many other ways are there to reverse a string? Your result isn't reversed, I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @Shawn no, he is right ie, last+first,last-1first-1. But op need to show his attempts.

Comment: I think I see the pattern: last, first, 2nd-from-last, 2nd, 3rd-from-last, 3rd, and so on. This should be a simple `for` loop. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: You also need to improve the question. Putting a single example and challenging readers to figure out the pattern is not the proper way to ask a question if you want help. You need to explain what you're trying to do clearly, show your attempt, and say what's going wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks for answering so far.
My Code so far:

$mystring = "1234";

$start = 0;
$end = strlen($mystring);
$direction = 1;

$new_str = '';

while ($start === $end) {
 if ($direction == 0) {
  $new_str .= substr($mystring, $start, 1);
  $start++;
  $direction = 1;
 } else {
  $new_str .= substr($mystring, $end, -1);
  $end--;
  $direction = 0;
 }
}

Comment: @anhaol add the above comment to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't help myself, I just had to write your code for you...

This just takes your string, splits it into an array, then builds up your output string taking letters from the front and end.

```
$output = '';
$input = str_split('123456');
$length = count($input);

while(strlen($output) < $length) {
    $currLength = strlen($output);
    if($currLength % 2 === 1) {
        $output .= array_shift($input);
    }
    else {
        $output .= array_pop($input);
    }
}

echo $output;
```

Example: http://ideone.com/Xyd0z6

Answer (score 3):

Not very different from Scopey's answer with a for loop:

```
$str = '123456';

$result = '';

$arr = str_split($str);

for ($i=0; $arr; $i++) {
    $result .= $i % 2 ? array_shift($arr) : array_pop($arr);
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "123456";
    $rev = "";

    $first = substr($str, 0, strlen($str)/2); 
    $last = strrev(substr($str, strlen($str)/2));
    $max = strlen($first) > strlen($last) ? strlen($first): strlen($last);

    for($count = 0; $count < $max; $count++)
        $rev .= (isset($last[$count])?$last[$count]:"" ) . (isset($first[$count])?$first[$count]: "");

    echo $rev;

?>
```

Output:

```
615243
```